# Fn::GetAZs + Fn::Select not co-operating

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

So I have this CloudFormation resource in my networking template:

```
Resources:
    ...

    PubSubnetAz2:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
        Properties:
            VpcId: !Ref Vpc
            CidrBlock: !FindInMap [VpcCidrs, !Ref "AWS::Region", pubsubnet2]
            AvailabilityZone: !Select
            - 1
            - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
```

I'm getting this error when I try to create this stack:

```
17:40:06 UTC-0700   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Subnet    PubSubnetAz2    Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 1
```

The template validates, I have a `PubSubnetAz1` block which is identical and passes, (it selects `index=0` though).

Am I using `Fn::GetAZs` wrong?

PS. I am using `us-west-2` region, as far as I can tell that has > 1 AZs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following template successfully deployed a VPC across multiple subnets in `us-west-2`:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  vpc1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      InstanceTenancy: default
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: false
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: My-VPC
  subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: ''
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      VpcId:
        Ref: vpc1
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Subnet-A
  subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - 1
        - Fn::GetAZs: ''
      CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
      VpcId:
        Ref: vpc1
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Subnet-B
```

I created the VPC manually, used [Hava](http://hava.io) to convert it to a JSON CloudFormation template, manually inserted the `Select` statements, then converted to YAML using [json2yaml.com](https://www.json2yaml.com/).

Comment: Excellent worked for me! No idea what I did differently but removing the `!Ref "AWS:Region"` and replacing with `""` does the job. Thanks John!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error while doing AWS Mysfits sample demo, for a second time. I found I needed to list the AZ I wished to use and the stack created successfully.

```
  PrivateSubnetTwo:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      CidrBlock: !FindInMap ['SubnetConfig', 'PrivateTwo', 'CIDR']
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Fn::GetAZs` documentation shows examples like:

```
mySubnet: 
  Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
  Properties: 
    VpcId: 
      !Ref VPC
    CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
    AvailabilityZone: 
      Fn::Select: 
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: ""
```

It has an empty Region, which apparently is equivalent to specifying `AWS::Region`.

It also shows an example using the full format as:

```
"Fn::GetAZs": ""
"Fn::GetAZs": { Ref: "AWS::Region" }
"Fn::GetAZs": "us-east-1"
```

Try some of those formats to see whether they work.